# Override block instead of override keyword on all methods

Tags: c++11, overriding

Is there any way I can make sure I can take advantage of override keyword without writing override after each method.

I have couple of points to desire such a thing

- Its error prone to mark each method override when you are dealing with legacy code and introducing the override keyword in the existing class
- You  have too many override methods
- Override methods maybe scattered around in class declaration mangled with bunch of other methods

I am looking for something like override block using scope, when any method is part of this block its same as writing override after the method signature.

I am pretty sure there is no such thing as override block in standard but can we implemnt something using macro or other stuff?

e.g.

```
class derived
{
   public:

      override {
              int blah();
               void blahBlah();
                .. so on
      };
};
```

Comment: why is it "error prone"? Do you mean you might forget to add it on some functions? If so, then you probably have another problem, which you should fix instead of looking for this kind of solutions. google "single responsibility principle".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way I can make sure I can take advantage of override keyword without writing override after each method.

I'm afraid not. There's nothing in the Standard regarding `override` blocks or anything similar.

If you feel like this should be added to the language, [write a proposal](https://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-proposal).